How to turn off vim editor by Ctrl + C in ubuntu
I have to turn off vim editor by Ctrl + C with code c language. However, i still can not to close vim follow my code. initial, i try to code to create process but i failed, and i try to create pthread. However i cannot to close vim editor
Here my code:
# IT007 Operating System#
# <Your name>, <your Student ID>#
# File: example_system.c#
######################################*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t idthread;
int loggg = 2;

void on_sigint1(){
    system("killall vim");
    loggg-=1;
}

void on_sigint2(){
    printf("You are pressed CTRL+C! Goodbye!");
    loggg-=1;
}


void* thread_open_vim(){
    system("vim abcd.txt");
    signal(SIGINT, on_sigint1);
    while(loggg!=1){};
    printf("%d", loggg);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
    printf("Hello IT007! I wil open vim editor now ^_^\n");
    pthread_create(
        &idthread,
        NULL,
        &thread_open_vim,
        NULL);
    signal(SIGINT, on_sigint2);  
    while(loggg!=0){};
}

Can you give me some solution. Thank you very much!

Your program is stuck calling the system(vi abc.txt) part until vi closes. The code after this line is never executed until you close vi. You could try using a child process to execute vi.
